# How do I segregate my changes in git branches when I'm not ready to commit?

Tags: git, branch

So, I have two git branches, master and testing. I checkout testing. I make some changes that are only halfway done and not ready to even stage let alone commit, I'm just screwing around. If I checkout master again, my screwy changes are included!! What??

So I could accidentally have some bad stuff in master just because it was not good enough to even commit in testing?

I thought branches would segregate my work. I tried staging even and that didn't seem to work. It seemed like I have to actually commit in testing or else my changes will stay visible (but uncommitted) in the files in my master branch.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what git-stash is for. You can stash your changes using

```
git stash
```

and get them back using

```
git stash apply
```

when you are done you should clear your stash using

```
git stash clear
```

If you want to just delete your changes you can use

```
git reset --hard
git clean -fd
```

Info taken from [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the best answer. Someone else also told me that the way to go is to get in the habit of using "git diff" whenever I come back to work after a while and want to be careful about the status. git status is useful too. So the point is to make sure things are clean, and if they aren't then stash is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply make a "`tmp`" branch, and commit in it.

```
git checkout -b tmp
```

That way, `master`, and `testing` are unchanged.
And you can resume your changes in `tmp` at any time.

Comment: That makes sense, but it requires me to actively commit still. Thanks for the option, it is a good one.